# Returning int from object x = ExecuteScalar() with nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

might not be the best approach to the problem, but I'm trying to query my user database in order to find out if a new user can register himself; there are 3 possible replies from the stored procedure:

1 - User is registered (Can't register, message A)
0 - User is not registered (Can register, success)
*null* - User is not loaded on database (Can't register, message B)

My class is as follows:

```
public int ValidateUser(string bi)
{
    SqlConnection cnConnect = new SqlConnection();
    cnConnect.ConnectionString = strConnect;
    cnConnect.Open();

    SqlCommand checkUser = new SqlCommand("sp_RegistaConnect", cnConnect);
    checkUser.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    checkUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@opt", 5));
    checkUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bi", bi));

    object userResult = checkUser.ExecuteScalar();
    cnConnect.Close();

    if (userResult is DBNull)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        int intReturn = (int)userResult;
        return intReturn;
    }
}
```

*My problem is, it always says the specified cast is not valid when converting to int. But one I ruled out the DBNull results, shouldn't it always be possible to cast to int? Maybe my brain is dying.*

*EDITED: My brain *was* dying - the database was returning a bool (bit)*

Problem is, when a null value returns from the database I always get an error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I also tryed a simpler version, with the same error result:

```
object userResult = checkUser.ExecuteScalar();
int intReturn = (int)(!Convert.IsDBNull(userResult) ? userResult : 2);
return intReturn;
```

How can I cast my sql return into an int, while dealing with null results?

Comment: It's been a while but isn't the check `userResult == DBNull.Value`?

Comment: Yep, it is, but just wondering, isn't it possible to alter the stored procedure to return 2 and skip the check?

Comment: Actually, the real problem was that the database was returning a bit, and so the object was a boolean, wich was messing up the conversion..
Me.Name, that would fix it, but I'd like to solve it in the application itself without altering the database in any way.

Comment: `userResult.Equals (DBNull.Value)`